# When using Gmail's "copy and transfer", do the data in the original account remain untouched or does it get deleted?

Tags: gmail, export

I'm using Google's "Control Your Content" tool under "My Account" and I'd like to "transfer your content," however, what I want to do is copy all data from one account to another without impacting the original account. In other words, I want to copy, not copy and delete original. Can anyone tell if this is the default behavior when you choose this option?

Comment: Well, shoot. It's amazing how much Googling I've done without finding a simple answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Creating an archive using [Control Your Content](https://myaccount.google.com/privacy#takeout) makes a copy of your data, but it doesn't actually delete anything.

From [the relevant help page](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3024190?hl=en):

> Note: Downloading your data does not delete it from Google’s servers.

Comment: Thanks! What I was really curious about though isn't the archive option, it's the "transfer to another email account" option. Any idea about that?

Comment: @JulianJohannesen Where do you see that option? I don't see it in Google settings under "Control your content" nor in Gmail settings under "Accounts and Imports."

Comment: Huh. I wonder if that's because I have the apps suite for nonprofits. On mine, under the archive options, there's another option to transfer one email account to another, which makes perfect sense for when an employee leaves and you want to move all of their content to someone else.

Comment: @JulianJohannesen That does make sense. I can't say for sure, but I would guess that option would be a move (cut and paste) rather than just a copy of the data.